# Java Servlet classpatth not working - Win 7 64bit

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, classpath

I am a new JAVA learner and i am compling java files into class files with CMD.
Yesterday i started with JAVA Servlet.
But CMD giving me error.

> servlet.java:2: error: package javax.servlet does not exist import
>   javax.servlet.http.*;

Then i searched google and every topic saying - set you CLASSPATTH.

Enviornment variables --> Path --> edit

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;

Done.
But again CMD giving me same error.

Code -

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class helloworld extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello World from GET method ");

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello World from POST method ");

    }
}
```

javac servlet.java
again same error

Comment: Path != classpath... You could have done a bit of research, and found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt). Oops, it seems I have to write some more text as you wanted reply not to be in one line, so be it...

Comment: How are you executing it? This should be accessed from an URL correctly mapped in your web.xml

Comment: @Eugenio he's far from that, stuck at compiling...

Comment: import javax.servlet.http.; // this won't compile

Comment: @PeterMmm frankly, I didn't even see the dot until you pointed out... However, the error message indicates that there was actually an asterisk after the dot, at least i nthe version he tried to compile...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling servlets with javac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791446/compiling-servlets-with-javac)

Comment: For you as newbie: it's Java and **not** JAVA!

Comment: I also tried. 
-cp [libraries] [other options] [file(s) to compile]
 But no luck

Answer (score 0):

set those libraries into the compiler classpath using java -cp [libraries] [other options] [file(s) to compile]

Comment: You tried literally as above, or what is exactly your command line ?

Comment: I tried this
java -cp [libraries] [other options] [file(s) to compile]

Comment: you should replace the parts between brackets with your own things of course :)

Comment: Yes dear i know, i have to replace brackets parts. I am going to try it on a 32Bit laptop today